# memcache avoid sql bursts

Tags: python, sql, performance, memcached, race-condition

I wan to know if there is a better way to handle "sql bursts" when using memcache.
let me explain with an example

```
object = memcache.get('some_key')
if object is None:
   #multiple request will cause a bursts of sqls
   object = Object() #this trigger some sql
   memcache.set('some_key',oject,60)
```

so a way I found to avoid sql bursts

```
object = memcache.get('some_key');
if(object is None or object.expire + rand(0,120) > now())
       #this not guarantees sql burst, but it will reduce them
       object = Object() #this trigger some sql
       object.expire = now() + 300
       memcache.set('some_key',object,60)
```

second option don't guarantees to avoid sql bursts and also I don't like to add expire to my object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few options mentioned on the [memcache wiki](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingTricks#Avoiding_stampeding_herd).